# In nextJs 14 is it a problem when i use the "use client" and a conditional rendering in the app/layout.tsx

Tags: typescript, next.js, routes

In my app i have a Navbar and this Navbar will be shown only when the routes is (/ or /teachers) the dashboard will not exists when the route is /dashboard.
I used a conditional rendering in the app/layout.tsx

```
"use client";
import "./globals.css";
import { CssBaseline, StyledEngineProvider } from "@mui/material";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import HomeNavbar from "@/components/home/HomeNavbar";

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  console.log(pathname);

  return (
    <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
      <CssBaseline />
      <html lang="en">
        <body id="__next">
          {
            pathname !== '/teachers' && <HomeNavbar />
          }
          {children}
        </body>
      </html>
    </StyledEngineProvider>
  );
}
```

I want to know if this approach correct or should i use an other approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on **[this link](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups#examples)**, you can create layouts for different routes and separate them by group. To group, you must use **parentheses** in folder names.
So you can make **different layouts** for routes like teachers

[image]

Comment: Thanks solved !
But i think there is an other issue now, how can add add not-found.tsx for my app ?

Comment: If it helped you accept please .
I found out that needs to create (layout) file in (app) folder. and it can just return (children) component. after that we should to create (not-found) page aside this layout. and done!